# CSS max-height and max-width property; parent size defined in % of window size

Tags: html, css

For my page layout I wanted to define a `.parent` element size relative to the window size:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  top: 0;
  left: 12.5%;
}
```

Inside this `.parent`, I want to display an image `.child` element that should be rescaled to the size of of `.parent` (the aspect ratio of the image fits that of `.parent`, so this won't be a problem):

```
.child {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
   <img class="child" src="/images/some_image.jpg">
   <img class="child" src="/images/another_image.jpg">
</div>
```

However, this does not seem to work as the image is not displayed at all.

I found that the computation of the height for max height can run into problems sometimes, which would result in the element not getting displayed. This seems to be the case here. Changing either the height / width of `.parent` or the max-height / max-width of `.child` to an absolute value (e.g. 500px) gets the image displayed, but this will not work with windows of different sizes (like with different screen resolutions).

How can I work around this problem? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: instead of using 100% height, you can use 100vh for full height of the window.

Comment: checkout the height and width of `.parent`? maybe the parent block's layout is not suitable, and the calculated height is 0px.

Comment: Using vh and vw for `.parent` gets me the image displayed and the size seems to be correct, but the position is off: The image is not positioned to the very top left corner of `.parent`, but rather moved to the bottom right. (Scrollbars appear.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `vh` and `vw` for the parent. Also, define the child's `height` and `width` instead of `max-height` and `max-width`:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 75vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 12.5%;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <img class="child" src="/images/some_image.jpg">
   <img class="child" src="/images/another_image.jpg">
</div>
```

Read more about css units [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. (Goes in the same direction as the comment by smehsan above.) Replacing the %-units for `.parent` with vh and vw is the important part.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`vh`** (viewport height) and **`vw`** (viewport width) units for sizing relative to the window.

- [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)
- [Relative Length Units - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 75vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 12.5vw;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="child">
  <img class="child">
</div>
```